# Android: trouble calling web service using AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-ksoap2

The code below usaually works good, but, If the code is executing and the connections is suddenly lost, an error often occurs. The error that I reported at bottom of this question seems to start near the line 430, that is:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope);
```

The following is the AsyncTask that do my work:

```
  private class CheckUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{
            private SoapObject response = null;
            ArrayList<String> methodsResult = new ArrayList<String>();      
    @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"CheckUpdate");
                Request.addProperty("Username", username);
                Request.addProperty("Password", password);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            final String soap_action = NAMESPACE+"CheckUpdate";

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope); //line 430, where error occurs!

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

            try {
                response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                ...here I use the returned data for build my array (methodsResult)

            SoapObject pi = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(0);
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return methodsResult; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] resultArr= result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
        new callWS().execute(resultArr);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
```

And here my error message:

```
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseProperties(ServiceConnectionSE.java:85)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:167)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at host.framework.ServicePromemoria$CheckUpdateTask.doInBackground(ServicePromemoria.java:430)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at host.framework.ServicePromemoria$CheckUpdateTask.doInBackground(ServicePromemoria.java:1)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-07 12:58:47.920: E/AndroidRuntime(31053):    ... 5 more
```

I'm not sure that the problem is related to leak of connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that none of your variables are set to null. If not, and the problem is http call simply handle the exception.

```
try { 
    androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope); //line 430, where error occurs!
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    enter code here
}
```

Hope it helps!